# OpenCV NDK-build not found

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, environment-variables, adt

So ive been wresting with this for like 3 hours so decided to ask a question. I must have read 10 different articles and still cant get it to work.

I am trying to set up OpenCV in an android project.

My environment variables are as follows in ".bash_profile"

```
export ANDROID_SDK="/Applications/eclipse/sdk"
export ANDROID_NDK="/Users/eharpham/Documents/eclipse/android-ndk-r8d"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"
```

Typing "env" in terminal shows these correctly:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/eclipse/sdk/tools:/Applications/eclipse/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/eharpham/Documents/eclipse/android-ndk-r8d
ANDROID_SDK=/Applications/eclipse/sdk
ANDROID_NDK=/Users/eharpham/Documents/eclipse/android-ndk-r8d
```

I am using macbook and adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522.

I have set the following:

ADT > Preferences > C/C++ > Environment:

```
Variable "ANDROID_NDK", Path "/Users/eharpham/Documents/eclipse/android-ndk-r8d"
```

ADT > Android > NDK >:

```
/Users/eharpham/Documents/eclipse/android-ndk-r8e
```

Project > Properties > C/C++ Build:

Changed ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd to ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build

Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment:

[image: Environment settings]

I have so tried this without the PATH above.

Getting the error:

```
Cannot run program "/ndk-build": Unknown reason
Error: Program "/ndk-build" is not found in PATH

PATH=    [/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/eclipse/sdk/too    ls:/Applications/eclipse/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/eharpham/Documents/eclipse/android-ndk-r8d]
```

The only error I can see is in Android Libraries:

[image]

This is driving me insane any assistance hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In ADT > Preferences > Android you should set the path to NDK: [image]. Yes, you already set in your environment and added it to the shell, but that's not enough. Eclipse Android plugin wants this info separately.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks but I have already done this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Look at this [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LDVhP.png). What is different in your project?

Comment: I see ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd rather than make

Comment: @Vlad: good eyes! It _should_ be `ndk-build` without path and without extension.

Comment: @AlexCohn How to set the path variable for NDK on windows?

Comment: @PrakharMohan: to run `ndk-build` from ADT (Eclipse), you don't need NDK on the system PATH.

Comment: @AlexCohn yes yes, got it. Was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have done the following steps and fixed my issue

1. select the project which has c++ lib,make sure you are on c++ view on eclipse
2. Right click when project selected and click on properties.
3. And make sure you set the right path of the ndk folder. It should be as variable as shown  in the screenshot or you can enter the full path of the ndk folder.
4. Click on the hammer it should compile your project.

[image: C/C++ Build Properties]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

In Eclipse, highlight your Project, then from the Eclipse menubar at the top, select 'Project->Properties'.

In the list on the left, click on the arrow next to the item 'C/C++ Build' and highlight the item 'Environment'.

In the box that reads 'Environment variables to set' you will have these 2 items, CWD and PWD (I see that you have PATH and ANDROID_NDK in yours also. Click the button that reads 'Add...'

In the box that appears, select the Name field and type in NDKROOT.

In the field that reads Value type in the path to where you unzipped the Android NDK (you should be able to see the ndk-build.cmd file there).

Click on 'Apply".  If this doesn't do the job then maybe experiment with removing the ANDROID_NDK item and the PATH items.